# Internet Explorer finds error in core Vue.js file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js

I have a Vue.js-based application which works fine in all browsers. Except, you guessed it...

When I try to open it in Internet Explorer, I get this error:

```
Expected identifier in vue.min.js, line 6 character 4872
```

When I navigate to that line/character, it shows that the error is in code that says:

```
var i=e.extends;
```

To be precise, IE places the cursor right after the dot in the expression above when I go to the error.

Vue.js is included from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js but I get the same issue if I include it locally.

Is there a solution to this besides telling users to use a different browser?

Comment: `extends` is reserved keyword in IE

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of Vue?

Comment: In the Vue universe, version 2.4.2 is really old.

Comment: Have you read this ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Compatibility-Note ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test with above Vue JS file in IE.

Based on my testing results, I find that this error can occur with older versions of IE like **IE-5, IE-7, IE-8**.

Error did not occurred with **IE-9, IE-10, IE-11**.

Here is a testing result.

[image]

Here, I want to suggest you to upgrade to IE 11 version which latest and only supported version currently.

Microsoft had already stopped providing support for other older versions of IE.

If you upgrade to IE 11 than it will be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but I can't force my users to upgrade their browsers. There is no solution other than that?

Comment: As we know that Which version of IE will not work with your app. So you can try to use JS code to identify the IE 5, IE 7 and IE 8 and try to inform your user that your site is not compatible with this specific version of IE and they can continue their work with any other browser.